# Why is the Date header not set when I make a WebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, api, storage, webrequest

Tonight I started a small project trying to create a C# library to access the [Google Storage API](https://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/developer-guide.html).  When you create any kind of request to the Google Storage API, you have to include the "Date" header in the web request.

I tried to create a WebRequest in C#, and noticed that I couldn't set the "Date" header manually.  According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), the Date property should be getting set automatically by the system.

My requests to Google are failing though due to a missing "Date" header.  Fiddler confirms that a Date header is not being sent in my request.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
WebRequest webRequest;
webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com");

String auth = "GOOG1 " + m_accessKey + ":" + CreateSignature();

webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
webRequest.ContentType = "text/html";

Stream objStream;
objStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

Any idea what could be going on?  Why isn't the Date header being sent with my web request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the TcpClient class, and creating my own headers, as outlined in this post:
http://www.issociate.de/board/goto/970687/HTTPWebRequest_Date_Header.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the [HttpWebRequest.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.date.aspx) property is DateTime.MinValue by default which will *not* send the Date header with the request.

So to set it all you should have to do is...

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com");

webRequest.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Comment: I think this property can only be set if you're targetting .NET 4.0:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.date.aspx

I definitely can't set this property when targetting .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using the tcp class and recode everything would be to use reflections to add them with the method "AddWithoutValidation". This will work in .Net 3.5 - a workaround

```
//request.Headers.Add("date", getIsoStringFromDate(DateTime.Now)); <- EXCEPTION in .Net 3.5

 //WORKAROUND
 Type type = request.Headers.GetType();
 BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
 MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("AddWithoutValidate", flags);
 object[] myPara = new object[2];
 myPara[0] = "date";
 myPara[1] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
 methodInfo.Invoke(request.Headers, myPara);
```